# Reporting Services Interactive Sort problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a set of reports defined for Reporting Services in SQL 2005.
I'm rendering the reports using the ReportViewer control inside an ASP.NET 3.5 application.
In all the reports I have a chart and a table where interactive sorting is implemented. The sorting works perfectly when I test it on the report server catalog page. But in the report viewer, sometime when clicking the sort, I will just get a white page.

One thing I noticed is adding values for some fields on the report will make it work again. For example I have a description field on the top of the report (above the chart. the table is below the chart). When the description field is empty, the sort fails (white page), when the description has a value, everything works.

The AsyncRendering value on the report viewer is set to "false". When I change to "true" the sort starts working. But that creates other issues I'm trying to avoid.

Also, the report viewer is displayed in an ASPX page that is loaded as an IFRAME in another page. In case that makes any difference

I think I'm following the instructions on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252090.aspx) page.

Is there a known issue with the sort?
Any workaround?

Comment: Haven't seen it myself, how much data is coming back in the report?

Comment: A table with maybe 300 rows. not more. I don't thinks it's a a size issue. As I said, just adding text in one field (populated from a parameter) fixes everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather then use the ReportViewer control why don't you have your IFrame link directly to your ReportServer accessing the ReportViewer page.
Set the IFrame source to:
http://ServerName/ReportServer?/ReportFolder/ReportName&rs:Command=Render